# AngularJS : ng-repeat inside a directive masks the directive's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an isolated scope directive that has its own controller.

The directive's template has access to that controller, except inside an ng-repeat where the entire controller is out of scope.

I don't know how to fix it.

If you have an ng-repeat inside an ng-controller, children of the ng-repeat inherit the functions of the ng-controller.

I would have thought that would be the case with custom directives, too - children inside the ng-repeat could still see the directive's controller - but as far as I can tell, they can't.

I'm still getting up to speed with Angular, so a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated. A downright answer would be appreciated even more. Something to do with transclusion? With which is getting compiled first?

Here is the directive:

```
angular.module('surverApp')
  .directive('surveyItems', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        itemList: '=',
        query: '='
        },
      templateUrl: 'views/directives/survey-items.html',
      replace: true,
      controller: 'SurveyItemsCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: true
    };
  })
  .controller('SurveyItemsCtrl', function(){
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.disableEdit = true;
    ctrl.disableToolbar = false;
    ctrl.showForm = false;
    ctrl.showDuplicate = false;
    ctrl.showTrash = false;

    ctrl.deleteItem = function(item) {
      console.log('ctrl.item in DELETE ITEM' ,item)

     .... functions removed for brevity
    };

  });
```

And here is its template. None of its functions fire.

```
<div>
  <pre>ctrl = {{ctrl | json}}</pre>  <<<<<=== THIS SHOWS THE CONTROLLER IS IN SCOPE
  <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.itemList | filter:ctrl.query"  class="ubi-box container-fluid">
    <pre>ctrl = {{ctrl | json}}</pre> <<<<<=== THIS SHOWS THE CONTROLLER IS NOT IN SCOPE
    <standard-right-toolbar ctrl="ctrl"></standard-right-toolbar>
    <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>
    <div ng-show="ctrl.showForm" class="ubi-box container-fluid">
      <!-- <survey-form model="item" disable-edit="ctrl.disableEdit" reset-fn="item = ctrl.resetUpdateFn(item)" submit-fn="ctrl.submitUpdateFn()" close-fn="ctrl.hideFormFn()"></survey-form> -->
      <survey-form model-el="item" disable-edit-el="ctrl.disableEdit" reset-fn="ctrl.resetUpdateFn(form,model)" submit-fn="ctrl.submitUpdateFn(form)" close-fn="ctrl.hideFormFn()"></survey-form>
      <pre>model = {{item | json}}</pre>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="ctrl.showDuplicate" class="ubi-box container-fluid">
      <standard-right-close-bar close-fn="ctrl.hideDuplicateFn()"></standard-right-close-bar>
      <h4 class="col-xs-12">Duplicating a survey will copy all the details and questions over to a new survey.</h4>
      <h3 class="col-xs-10">Click the copy button to procede.</h3>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.copy(item)" title="Duplicate">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- <div ng-show="ctrl.showTrash" class="ubi-box container-fluid"> -->
      <div ng-show="ctrl.showTrash" class="ubi-box container-fluid">
      <standard-right-close-bar close-fn="ctrl.hideTrashFn()"></standard-right-close-bar>
      <h4 class="col-xs-12">Deleting a survey is a very serious matter. It will permanently remove every question and every answer in every questionnaire in every edition in the survey.</h4>
      <h3 class="col-xs-10">Click the trashcan only if you are sure!</h3>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="button" ng-click="ctrl.deleteItem(item)" title="Delete">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

PS I had it working fine inside an ng-controller. But then I read ng-controllers are being outlawed in Angular 2.0, so I thought I'd get in some practice using directive controllers rather than ng-controllers and I wrapped the ng-repeat in a directive instead of an ng-controller.
So far, so stumped . . .

Comment: try to simplify your example and reduce all the irrelevant clutter. Here's a reduced version that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/zf4KWJbiVGRz5iFAu3OT?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I don't see that you did anything different from me, and yet your one works. I gather this means ng-repeat does not hide the controller from scope, and that I am simply doing something else wrong? Or is there something you've changed that I'm missing? Noted about simplifying the example.

Comment: That's exactly what it means, and why it is important to reduce the code before asking a question. It not only allows you to zero-in on the problem, but also helps us read and understand your issue. win-win

Comment: The suggestion I simplify the example was what fixed it for me. When I removed the clutter in the middle of the template it started working. Turned out one of the directives inside the ng-repeat had a controller with the same name as the main controller and that hid the main controller from scope.

Comment: heh, funny... :)  I suggest you then delete the question